# CreateProcess error=2 running javadoc from Ant

Tags: ant

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error message

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Tara\workspace\Testing\build.xml
doc:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\Tara\workspace\Testing\doc 
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Tara\workspace\Testing\doc 
  [javadoc] Generating Javadoc
  [javadoc] Javadoc execution

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Tara\workspace\Testing\build.xml:24: Javadoc failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javadoc.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Total time: 206 milliseconds
```

when I run this in Eclipse?

```
<project name="SimpleBuildScript" basedir="." default="doc">
<property file="build.properties"/>
<target name="compile" description="Compiles the Task">
    <delete dir="${class.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${class.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="classes"/>
</target>

<target name="clean" description="Delete all generated files">
        <delete dir="${class.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="doc" description="generate documentation">
    <delete dir="${doc.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${doc.dir}"/>
        <javadoc sourcepath="${source.dir}" destdir="${doc.dir}"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 27):

Providing you have a jdk installed and added to Eclipse:

1. Windows->Preferences Java->Installed
2. JREs->Add

You can then

1. Right click on build.xml
2. Select Run As->Ant Build... **note the ellipsis!**
3. Switch to JRE tab
4. Select the jdk from the list

Credit for a similar solution:
http://blog.darevay.com/2008/12/running-javadoc-ant-task-from-eclipse/

Comment: I had a JRE selected, but didn't seem to like it, I changed it to the JRE inside my latest JDK folder that did the trick!

Comment: I had buildpath set to JDK but still it was reporting missing file. But buildpath for Ant is different. Thanks for making it clear

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same issue and solved it by adding an additional JREs definitions under:

`Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs`

[image: Installed JREs Eclipse screenshot]

At the time it failed, I was using `Jre7` in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7` then I have added and selected `Jre` in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre`.

Comment: After running into an identical error on a later Java upgrade, I found that this can also be caused by not having the appropriate bin directory in the Windows PATH (e.g., `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin` in the above example).

Answer (score 3):

Change Ant Config :  [Edit Configuration] -> [JRE] -> Change jre to jdk 
and I solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

javadoc is not in the path. With newer ant you can provide attribute (executable) to specify exe location.  See documentation [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add javadoc.exe to your build path.

1. From the start menu, click on Control Panel >  System (use classic view) to view system properties.
2. In the System Properties window, click on Advanced to the left.
3. Click on Environment Variables.
4. In the list of System Variables, select Path and then press the Edit button. a window that allows you to alter the value of the Path variable.
5. At the end of the text for the Path variable, add a semicolon and the directory path to Java (no spaces): eg. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin

Comment: With more recent JDK's (Java 8), Oracle prepends the following path to the Windows PATH variable: `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Oracle\Java\javapath`, so you may need to remove that as well (path varies by Windows version of course). Also note the [Ant FAQ](https://ant.apache.org/faq.html#CreateProcess_error_2) on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the javadoc.exe is on your path; this error usually means the ant task cannot find the executable