# javadoc.exe not found while running ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am trying to run some basic ant scripts and while doing so facing following error:

```
D:\{user...}\build.xml:31: Javadoc failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javadoc.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have already tried searching for solution and came to following solutions:
[CreateProcess error=2 running javadoc from Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643319/createprocess-error-2-running-javadoc-from-ant)

- I am already using JDK. Still facing the issue. javadoc.exe is already present in jdk\bin.
- I am using inbuilt Ant which came with ecplise Kepler Service Release 2.
- If I remove 'docs' target, it's running perfectly.

This is my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Ant-Test" default="main" basedir=".">
  <!-- Sets variables which can later be used. -->
  <!-- The value of a property is accessed via ${} -->
  <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
  <property name="build.dir" location="bin" />
  <property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
  <property name="docs.dir" location="docs" />

  <!-- Deletes the existing build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Creates the  build, docs and dist directory-->
  <target name="makedir">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
  </target>

  <!-- Compiles the java code (including the usage of library for JUnit -->
  <target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}"></javac>
  </target>

  <!-- Creates Javadoc -->
  <target name="docs" depends="compile">
    <javadoc packagenames="com.ant.vogellaTut.*" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
      <!-- Define which files / directory should get included, we include all -->
       <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**" />
           </fileset>
    </javadoc>
  </target>

  <!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
  <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\antTraining.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.ant.vogellaTut.test.Test" />
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="main" depends="compile, jar, docs">
    <description>Main target</description>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: is environment variable ok for `javadoc`?

Comment: I was using jdk which was not under program files folder. I made the entry of jdk/bin in Path variable and restarted the machine and problem is solved. thanks.

Comment: it was mentioned in the question only that u linked. anyway enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

What the error is telling you is that it can't find "javadoc.exe" in the Path.

Try outputting the path system variable from within your ant script, you can use something along the lines of:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<echo message="path = ${env.PATH}"/>
```

and verify that the path to your javadoc.exe is listed in there.